# Directive allow from not work for only one ip in .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I have .htaccess file for wordpress.  There is code

```
    <Files wp-login.php>
      order deny,allow
      deny from all
      allow from 46.61.xxx
      allow from 91.211.xxx
      allow from 176.14.xxx
    </files>
```

2 of these ip - works,  i.e. i can enter from 46.61.xxx and 176.14.xxx, but i can't enter from 91.211.xxx. What problem could it be?

Comment: I would guess, the IP is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give it a try without those xxx's, check the apache [documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_access_compat.html#allow)

```
<Files wp-login.php>
      order deny,allow
      deny from all
      allow from 46.61
      allow from 91.211
      allow from 176.14
</files>
```

Comment: This sort of works of course, but it opens a whole range of IP addresses. Actually, it opens about 65,000 IP addresses for each "allow from", which makes roughly 195,000 IP addresses overall. If this is what you intended, fine!